# Haskell TransformListComp extension

Tags: haskell, language-extension

I read [this guide](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/PthariensFlame/guide-to-ghc-extensions/list-comprehension-extensions) about haskell language extensions and was somewhat confused by the TransformListComp explanation. I tried to rewrite all the TransformListComp expression without the sugar but I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Also I think there is a mistake in the guide: The example for "then group using clauses" is impossible as "(groupBy (==))" is not of the right type ("Eq a" can't be used)

```
[foo |  x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi,
        then f,
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ]

==
[foo |  f x1 <- xs1,
        f x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        f xi <- xsi,
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ]

-------------------


[foo |  x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi,
        then f by exp,
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ]

==

f (\(x1,x2,...,xi) -> exp) [(x1,x2,...,xi) | 
        x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi]

>>=(\(x1,x2,...,xi) -> 
    [foo |  
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ])


-------------------

[foo |  x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi,
        then group using f,
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ]

==

map unzipI (f [(x1,x2,...,xi) | 
        x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi])

>>=(\(xs1,xs2,...,xsi) -> 
    [foo |
        x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi,
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ])

unzipI :: [(t1,t2,...tn)] -> ([t1],[t2]..,[tn])

-------------------

[foo |  x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi,
        then group by exp using f,
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ]

==

 map unzipI (f (\(x1,x2,...,xi) -> exp) [(x1,x2,...,xi) | 
        x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi])

>>=(\(xs1,xs2,...,xsi) -> 
    [foo |
        x1 <- xs1,
        x2 <- xs2,
        ...
        xi <- xsi,
        xj <- xsj,
        ...
        xn <- xni
    ])

unzipI :: [(t1,t2,...tn)] -> ([t1],[t2]..,[tn])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite

```
[ foo | x1 <- xs1
      , x2 <- xs2
      , then f
      , x3 <- xs3 ]
```

more correctly as

```
[ foo | (x1, x2) <- f [ (x1, x2) | x1 <- xs1
                                 , x2 <- xs2 ]
      , x3 <- xs3 ]
```

The `groupBy` mistake seems to have been fixed in the meantime, the article's example works.

Another useful source on this extension is in this [blog post](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-07-list-comprehensions.html), also see the original article [comprehensive comprehensions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/comprehensive-comprehensions-comprehensions-with-order-by-and-group-by/).